# DiscordJS: Create Thread for bot's own message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want the bot to create a Thread to it's own message, but I cant figure out how to do that. I've managed to make it create a Thread to the user's message, but thats about it.

```
client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
    if(message.author.bot) return;

    if(message.channel.id == config.suggestChannelID) {
        const suggestEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#FEE75C')
            .setTitle(`${message.content}`)
            .setAuthor({
                name: `${message.member.displayName}`,
                iconURL: `[REDACTED]`,
                url: `[REDACTED]`
            })
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter({
                text: 'SuggestManager',
                iconURL: '[REDACTED]',
            });

        const discussThread = await message.startThread({
            name: 'name',
            autoArchiveDuration: 60,
            type: 'GUILD_PUBLIC_THREAD',
            reason: 'test'
        });

        await message.reply({embeds: [suggestEmbed]}).then(sentEmbed => {
            sentEmbed.react("")
            sentEmbed.react("")
        });

        message.delete(message.id);
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

added const threadAuthor to save the original message author & replaced sentEmbed with function (message)

```
client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
    if(message.author.bot) return;

    if(message.channel.id == config.suggestChannelID) {
        //added this
        const threadAuthor = message.member.displayName;

        const suggestEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#FEE75C')
            .setTitle(`${message.content}`)
            .setAuthor({
                name: `${message.member.displayName}`,
                iconURL: `[REDACTED]`,
                url: `[REDACTED]`
            })
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter({
                text: 'SuggestManager',
                iconURL: '[REDACTED]',
            });
        
        //changed this
        await message.reply({embeds: [suggestEmbed]}).then(function (message) {
            message.react("")
            message.react("")
            message.startThread({
                name: `${threadAuthor}-${message.createdTimestamp}`,
                autoArchiveDuration: 60,
                type: 'GUILD_PUBLIC_THREAD'
            });
        });

        message.delete(message.id);
    };
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).